# Bootstrap Nav not working correctly in MS Edge/IE

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I created a website with a navigation under the header. When scrolling over the navigation its position gets fixed at the top and its color changes.

Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox but in Edge or Internet Explorer the navigation changes color everytime the user scrolls.

The CSS for the inverted navbar:

```
.top-nav-invert {
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.07);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.07);
}

.top-nav-invert a {
  color: #000 !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

JS:

```
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 320) {
      $(".navbar").addClass("top-nav-invert");
    } else {
      $(".navbar").removeClass("top-nav-invert");
    }
```

To better understand what I did, I put the rest of the code into a codepen:

http://codepen.io/marcomai/pen/OMjgXp

Why is this a problem in IE and what could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a closer look at this issue, and see if we can identify areas of improvement of the Microsoft Edge team to make. In the meantime, I was able to confirm that a quick debounce will result in a much better experience.

Instead of having the following:

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    /* Logic Here */
});
```

Do the following:

```js
var debounce;

$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    clearTimeout( debounce );
    debounce = setTimeout(function () {
        /* Logic Here */
    }, 50);        
});
```

In the meantime, I'll continue to look into this demo.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Not the perfect solution but definitely much better already.

Comment: @s4ndm4nn As a general rule, you want to be very careful with things like `window.onscroll`, as these types of events can be fired many times each second. You generally don't want to make trips out to the DOM, or update layout on each handled event. This could result in extra battery consumption, dropped frames, and more. Also, please consider accepting this answer if you feel it helped in your situation.